# How to open file from Error List in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I get used that when I double clicked on error line in Error List the file opened in the regular tabs (on the top).

Nowadays after a recent update they changed it that the file openes on the bottom tabs (next to Error List, Find Results etc.).

Does anybody know how to change it back?